# Trying to click radio button option by name/value in Selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium and am able to select a value from a drop down list but can't seem to do it for a radio button. Here's the code I use for the drop down list:

```
public void SelectValueById(string element, string text) {
    //Get hold of the dropdown box by Name
    IWebElement dropDown = commondriver.FindElement(By.Id(element));

    //Place the drop down into selectElement
    SelectElement clickThisitem = new SelectElement(dropDown);

    //Select the Item from dropdown by Text
    clickThisitem.SelectByText(text);
}
```

This works fine. I'd like to do the same thing with a radio button. I want to pass in the same two parameters--radio button id or xpath, and the name/value of the option to select--and have the function click the correct option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A radio button is not considered a `<select>` element.  it is a `<input>` element with the attribute `type='radio'`.  Checking and Clicking are both sufficient.  (clicking moreso sometimes due to ajax binds, etc)

```
IWebElement radio = commondriver.FindElement(By.Id(element));
radio.click(); // this will work
radio.check(); // so will this.
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but this seems like it will just click one specific option that I pass in. But I want to be able to separately specify the radio button group, and the specific option to select. Because the app I'm testing has questions that don't change (like "Eye Color") and other options that I want to be able to change and pass in via an Excel spreadsheet ("Blue", "Green", "Hazel", etc.). I hope this makes sense.

Comment: wait wait, what do you mean by radio?  are you actually referring to `<select multiple='multiple'>`?

Comment: No, I mean regular radio buttons--the round dots that you can click on, and only one can be selected at a time. (I don't have enough rep to post images). Maybe I'm making a mistake in thinking that a radio button (or rather, group of radio buttons) is a list of values like a select element is.

Comment: It's not a list of values.  semantically, radio buttons are several `<input type='radio' name='my_radio' value='1'>` `<input type='radio' name='my_radio' value='2'>` my solution is what you want.